# Ansible inventory can't be parsed

Tags: ansible

I am trying to play my first playbook on the new local machine.
I have lost my previous one, so I am not able to look into it's configuration files.
I have prepared two virtual machines for testing Ansible.
The first one is an Ansible machine with whole config and playbooks, etc. The second one is the machine on which I want to make changes with playbook.

I've got the error: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available, but I declare inventory file in the command line:

`ansible-playbook -i inventory/dockers.yml yum-update.yml`

I read in Ansible documentation that config in /etc/ansible shouldn't be taken into consideration, because I used the -i option during command execution.

This is my inventory file. I believe that there must be something there, but I can't see it:

```
all:
  hosts:
    machine02:
      ansible_host: 192.168.1.16
  yumek:
    hosts:
      machine02:
    vars:

  ansible_user: test
  remote_user: root
```

The output of the `[ansible1@host01 ~]$ ansible-inventory --list is`:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with yaml plugin: Parsed empty YAML file
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with constructed plugin: /etc/ansible/hosts is empty
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    }, 
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some serious indentation problems with what you've posted. Take a look at the example YAML files in [this documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Comment: What is the output of `ansible-inventory --list` ?

Comment: @OliverGaida I added the output of the command you ask me for. Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 3):

I played playbook with option -i from $HOME location of non-root user, despite that Ansible did not use indicated inventory.

Solution was very simple, just changing inventory location path in the main config /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg on root account to:

```
inventory      = ~/inventory_folder
```

Unfortunately, still I do not know why Ansible did not respect -i option in the command.